# Smallest water proof pannier bag to fit a 14" MacBook Pro

Tags: bags

Roughly 8 to 9 out of 10 times that I commute from my home to my office I go by bike -- direct way about 30 mins, but if I feel like especially the rides back can last up to 2 hours ;-) --  so transporting clothing etc. can be handled easily either on those rare times when I don't or by using my current 26 liter pannier bag that however is way too spacious and heavy for what I need most of the time: the only item that I really have to transport to and from the office each single time is my laptop.

Hence I would like to find the lightest and smallest waterproof pannier bag (don't like rucksacks when commuting) that can be attached to a Tubus Fly and that is able to fit a 14" MacBook Pro. As this is less about a bag's easily searchable volume in liters but more about its interior dimensions' compatibility with the device's size... Does anybody know of a super compact bag that fulfils this requirement?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm afraid shopping recommendations are off topic here

Comment: What about frame bags, at least if your frame isn't super-small and you can sacrifice carrying bottles, there are quite a few in more square-ish shapes that will fit something like a MacBook.

Comment: Relevant: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/79371/6852

Answer (score 2):

Get a hard shell case for the laptop and attach pannier fittings to it. Then put the laptop in a plastic bag in the case, and cover the case with one of those elasticated bag covers, whenever there's a chance of rain.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making my own bag to suit my bike and laptop.

The work laptop sits inside a stiff "box" which fits snugly inside a heavy nylon pouch, which has straps and clips to hold it to the bike.

Lots of waterproofing silicon spray helps protect the contents.   And it is reasonably aero, at least for wind from the front.

I have done something right, because this setup survived a collision with a car from the left-rear quarter (basically the camera's viewpoint.)

[image]

[image]